# Can I do this with JS array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, naming-conventions

I want to create an array called `currentArray`, but I want its contents to be made up from a different array. Basically a copy. However, I want to affect which array is being copied into `currentArray` with a variable (int).

Here's what I mean:

```
function region(number)
{
        var regionArray1 = [1093, 1276, 436, 541];
        var regionArray2 = [563, 747, 310, 423, 744, 947, 601, 715];

        var currentArray = (regionArray+number)[]; 
}
```

---

`number` will be either 1 or 2. What is the correct way to do this, if I can? I've also tried `var currentArray = ("regionArray"+number)[];` but that doesn't seem to be the right way either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a two dimensional array:

```
function region(number) {
    var regionArrays = [
        [1093, 1276, 436, 541],
        [563, 747, 310, 423, 744, 947, 601, 715]
    ];
    var currentArray = regionArrays[number - 1];

}
```

Comment: I got a lot of great answers, but I'm picking this one because not only is it a correct answer but he also noticed that I said that the `number` variable would be 1 or 2. ;)

Answer (score 5):

The "best" way would be to make `regionArray` an array of arrays (or an Object of arrays):

```
function region(number)
{
    var regionArray = {
                        "1": [1093, 1276, 436, 541], 
                        "2": [563, 747, 310, 423, 744, 947, 601, 715]
                      };

    var currentArray = regionArray[number]; 
}
```

Comment: No need for the object keys overhead - an array of array is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
function region(i) {
    var regionArray = [
        [1093, 1276, 436, 541],
        [563, 747, 310, 423, 744, 947, 601, 715]
    ];

    var currentArray = regionArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a switch/case. `eval` should not be used in cases where you know all the information that needs to be executed.

```
function region(n) {
    // define arrays ...
    switch(n) {
        case 1 : currentArray = regionArray1; break;
        case 2 : currentArray = regionArray3; break;
    }
}
```

If this extends to more than 2 you can have an array of arrays and simply assign `currentArray = arrayChoices[n];`

Answer (score 0):

why not this :

```
function region(number)
{
        var regionArray = [];
        regionArray[0] = [1093, 1276, 436, 541];
        regionArray[1] = [563, 747, 310, 423, 744, 947, 601, 715];

        var currentArray = regionArray[ number ]; 
}
```

Comment: This is syntactically invalid.